# My Mongo is not returning an object with data

Tags: json, database, mongodb, server

I'm trying to connect to my mongodb atlas, so that I can host the site on Heroku. When I try to use my "/" get route, it is loading the website but in the console log for my mongo data, it's returning an empty array. I've never used atlas before so I don't know if I have the server set up wrong or what.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();

const moonliteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  movie1: String,
  announceImg: String,
  announceHead: String,
  announceText: String,
  movie2: String,
  movie3: String,
  movie4: String,
});

// Register the "moonliteCollection" model with Mongoose
const Moonlite = mongoose.model("moonliteCollection", moonliteSchema, "moonliteCollection");

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// Connect to MongoDB using Mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://USER:PWD@moonlitecluster.fhjc5xd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB!");

    app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const data = await Moonlite.find({});
        console.log(data);
        const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(jsonData);

        const indexHtml = fs.readFileSync("index.html", "utf8");

        const modifiedHtml = indexHtml.replace(
          "<!-- REPLACE_WITH_JSON -->",
          `<script>
            var serverData = ${jsonData};
            console.log(serverData);
            document.getElementById("slide1").style.backgroundImage = "/images/" + serverData[0].movie1;
            document.getElementById("slide2").style.backgroundImage = "/images/" + serverData[0].movie2;
            document.getElementById("slide3").style.backgroundImage = "/images/" + serverData[0].movie3;
            document.getElementById("slide4").style.backgroundImage = "/images/" + serverData[0].movie4;
            document.getElementById("announceImg").style.backgroundImage = "/images/" + serverData[0].announceImg;
            document.getElementById("announceHead").innerHTML = serverData[0].announceHead;
            document.getElementById("announceText").innerHTML = serverData[0].announceText;
          </script>`
        );

        res.send(modifiedHtml);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed to retrieve data from MongoDB:", err);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      }
    });

    app.get("/all-data", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const result = await Moonlite.find().exec();
        if (result) {
          res.status(200).json(result);
        } else {
          console.log('Uh Oh, something went wrong');
          res.status(500).json({ message: 'something went wrong' });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error retrieving data:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
      }
    });

    app.put(
      "/homeUpdate/:movie1/:movie2/:movie3/:movie4/:announceImg/:announceHead/:announceText",
      async (req, res) => {
        try {
          const updatedData = {
            movie1: req.params.movie1,
            movie2: req.params.movie2,
            movie3: req.params.movie3,
            movie4: req.params.movie4,
            announceImg: req.params.announceImg,
            announceHead: req.params.announceHead,
            announceText: req.params.announceText,
          };

          const filter = { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6495f0d65bafa39e36c4ec39") };
          const options = { new: true }; // Return the updated document

          console.log(filter);
          const updatedDocument = await Moonlite.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updatedData, options).exec();

          if (!updatedDocument) {
            console.log("Document not found");
            return res.status(404).send("Document not found");
          }

          console.log("Document updated successfully:", updatedDocument);
          res.status(200).send("Document updated successfully");
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Failed to update document:", err);
          res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        }
      }
    );

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
      console.log(`API server running on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}!`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to connect to MongoDB:", err);
  });
```

I've tried altering all of the code, and trying a bunch of different things. I'm just a little out of my element in this area.

Comment: I edited your post to take the login credentials out.   That said, I was able to connect to `moonliteCollection` and there are no docs in it (count == 0) so your `Moonlite.find()` calls will return empty arrays.